# How to remove react from build from custom component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-redux

I am learning how to make `custom component or library`  and publish on `npm`. I found a `free` tutorial here:

https://www.udemy.com/course/your-custom-react-component/learn/lecture/13561884#overview
github link

https://github.com/davidcsejtei/custom-button

But I am facing one problem .`he created a simple component custom button`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import '../style/button.scss';

export default class CustomButton extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <button>Custom button</button>
        );
    }

}
```

but when we create a build it include `react library` in his build so now it's size increase to 7.5kb.`It should be below`  2kb `as it is small component and it is used in another  project`

In other ways custom component use react dependency from there parent component . Can we remove this react dependency in build ?

Here is the webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'custom-button.js',
        library: 'custom-button',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
    ]
}
```

any update ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to exclude `react` out of your build with `webpack`, you just simply declare `externals` in your configuration like below:

```
externals: {
  react: "react",    
}
```

As you output with your `umd` module above, it will require `react` as the dependency in the build which means it will consume the `react` at the parent (consuming) repo:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory(require("react"));
 // ...
```